# How to allocate a struct and then increase its size?

Tags: c++, memory, struct, new-operator

I have a struct *data*

```
struct dataStruct{
  int mID;
  float mX;
};
```

a *fillData* method

```
void fillData(data *pt)
{
  pt = new data(10);
}
```

and the *main* function

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  dataStruct *myData;
  fillData(myData);

  myData[4].mID = 10;

  std::cout <<  myData[4].mID << " " << myData[5].mID << std::endl;
}
```

and a couple of questions:

- how can allocate *myData* inside the *fillData* method so that the allocation is not local to *fillData*?
- Can the size of *myData* be *increased* by later calls to *fillData* and thus changing the size from i.e. 10 to 100 ?
- Would it be better to manage the *dataStruct* pointer using **std::unique_ptr** ?

Comment: Use a reference for the pointer parameter: `void fillData(data*& pt)`

Comment: For a C++ question, this is very C. Use e.g. `std::vector` and be done.

Comment: "*How to allocate a struct and then increase its size?*" You can't increase the size of a struct at runtime.

Comment: use malloc and realloc whenever needed to reallocate again

Comment: Du you mayhaps mean `void fillData(data*& pt) { pt = new data[10]; }`?

Comment: `pt = new data(10)` This does not create an array of 10 structs. Please use vectors to avoid these mistakes.

Comment: For part 1 you could also just return the `data` pointer e.g. `dataStruct *fillDataRet(){  return new dataStruct[10];}`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing at what you want, as it is not clear.

Here is a much better way to handle a collection of objects whose size needs to change dynamically:

```
struct dataStruct
{
    dataStruct() : mID(0), mX(0.0f) {} // default to value 0

    dataStruct(int mID, float mX) : mID(mID), mX(mX) {}

    int mID;
    float mX;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    std::vector<dataStruct> myData(10); // create 10 objects with values 0

    myData[4].mID = 10;

    std::cout <<  myData[4].mID << " " << myData[5].mID << std::endl;

    // now resize to 100 objects, with 0 values for any new objects
    myData.resize(100);

    std::cout <<  myData[4].mID << " " << myData[99].mID << std::endl;
}
```

Live example:
http://ideone.com/5nyPOp

No memory leaks! No uninitialized data (which is used in your original code). And good debug compilers will bounds check for you.

Comment: Wow, very nice response. So essentially you create a vector that contains dataStruct objects. Can someone push_back objects to the vector, instead of adding the first 10 and then re-sizing to 100?


Also, i am not sure what the following line does:

    dataStruct(int mID, float mX) : mID(mID), mX(mX) {}

Comment: @charis Yes you can either resize or push_back individually. That is a constructor using the initialization list.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, `fillData()` needs to accept either a reference

```
void fillData(data *&pt)      // makes change of pt visible to the caller
{
  pt = new data(10);
}

int main()
{
    data *pointer;
    fillData(pointer);
}
```

or a pointer to a pointer

```
void fillData(data **pt)      // makes change of *pt visible to the caller
{
  *pt = new data(10);
}

int main()
{
    data *pointer;
    fillData(&pointer);    // pass the address of pointer
}
```

For the second question, somehow `fillData()` needs to be told how many objects to allocate, and be able to release.

```
void fillData(data *&pt, int size)
{
    delete [] pt;
    pt = new data[size];
}

int main()
{
    data *pointer = NULL;    //  otherwise first call of fillData() will fail on the delete statement

    fillData(10);
     //   use pointer like an array of 10 elements

    fillData(20);   //   note previous contents of pointer are lost

     //   use pointer like an array of 10 elements
}
```

Answer to your third question:  Short answer: No.

Longer answer to your third question:   If you want a resizable set of your `data`, use a standard container (like `std::vector<data>`) instead.   One advantage of this is that standard containers can be resized cleanly (e.g. if resizing from 10 to 20 elements, the first ten elements are retained).

Note:  it is possible to resize things allocated directly with `operator new` (e.g. with additional book-keeping to keep track of current and new sizes) but I have not done it in the examples above - because using a standard container is a vastly better approach in practice.